# VBScript Control A

Tags: vbscript, controls

I can't figure out how to press Control A (HighLight everything) using VBS, what is it?

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 500
object.SendKeys "^A"
```

I get this

---

### Windows Script Host

Script: C:\Users\Shane own\Desktop\A.vbs
Line:   4
Char:   1
Error:  Object required: 'object'
Code:   800A01A8
Source:     Microsoft VBScript runtime error

---

### OK

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SendKeys` is a method of the WshShell class. You created two WshShell objects (`objShell` and `WshShell`). Just use one of those objects to call the `SendKeys` method.

```
objShell.SendKeys "^A"
```

Comment: OH right, well, no error but it didn't highlight anything

Comment: You need to use [`AppActivate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) first to activate the window you wish to send keystrokes to.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/by0FWDyC       Theres what i'm doing (example) Any idea whats not working??

Comment: Few things: 1) You only need one WshShell object. 2) Use `Run` vs `Exec`. 3) Call `AppActivate` _before_ issuing any `SendKeys` statements.

Comment: Which part? Post an updated sample below your original, if you'd like and I'll take a look.